# Not able to start mesos-master

Tags: apache, mesos, mesosphere

I have installed Mesos on Centos 6.8. Now when I start mesos-master using following command:

```
mesos-master --ip=10.150.240.10 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos/
```

I'm getting the below error:

> mesos-master: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you installed Mesos? Form source or package?

Comment: From package. http://repos.mesosphere.com/el/7/noarch/RPMS/mesosphere-el-repo-7-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: This looks like version for 7.1 try with 6.5 http://repos.mesosphere.com/el-testing/6/x86_64/RPMS/mesos-1.1.0-1.0.98.rc1.centos65.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Yes, that worked.

Comment: Cool! I copied it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like version for 7.1 try with version for 6.5 available [here](http://repos.mesosphere.com/el-testing/6/x86_64/RPMS/mesos-1.1.0-1.0.98.rc1.centos65.x86_64.rpm)